# Is it secure to pass a fixed API key in request body

Tags: node.js, rest, security, authentication

I am currently building a bot using node.js
I would like to secure one route only to be used for cronjob task
I looked at all the solutions on the internet and I feel they are overkill for my situation.

The way I am securing the route is through passing a fixed authentication token in the body of a post request (HTTPS) and i check the authentication in node.js as following:

```
  app.post("/message", (req, res) => {
    if (
      typeof req.body.auth === undefined ||
      req.body.auth !== process.env.auth ||
      typeof req.body.message === undefined
    ) {
      return res.sendStatus(403);
    }
    // rest of the code
  });
```

Is this secure enough? if not why? and what method should i use to secure this route?

Comment: the norm yet is to use HTTPS then there is less risk that the key is stolen during the request. but server side, the stockage of the datas are more vulnerable then it is better the stock the key hash instead of the key itself.

Comment: I am not sure I understood the question correctly. Do you mean that you send a token back and forth between a server and a client and check if the same thing that was sent from the server, is returned to it by the client? Also, what are you trying to protect this way (e.g. the session)?

Comment: it is not sent back and forth. only one predefined secret that is sent to the server in the body of the post request. the server will only compare it with the stored hash to check if it is correct.